# Seemingly correct BFS implementation finding paths, but not *shortest* paths (weightless edges)

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

Below is an attempt at an algorithm to find shortest paths in a graph with weightless edges, with one added constrain: a set of nodes that cannot be in the path.  So instead of finding the absolute shortest path between nodes, it finds the shortest path that doesn't include certain nodes.

*Wordnode* is the node class, and *HashSet avoids* is the set of nodes that must be avoided.  The only place in the algorithm where this comes into play is when checking whether to add a node to the queue.  If it's in *avoids* (or if it's already been visited), don't add it.  I believe the effect of this check should be equivalent to temporarily removing any edges into and out of nodes in *avoids*, though by using the HashSet I avoid actually mutating the data structure.

I thought the algorithm was working until I managed to get *shorter* paths by adding words to *avoids*.  e.g., if *avoids* is empty, then for *shortestPath(A, Z, {})* it might return (A, B, E, C, F, L, D, Z), but upon adding E and C to *avoids* and calling *shortestPath(A, Z, {E, C})*, I get (A, R, K, Z), which is shorter...

The graph I'm using has thousands of nodes, but I have checked that both (A, B, E, C, F, L, D, Z) *and* (A, R, K, Z) are valid paths.  The problem is that the algorithm is returning a path of length 8 when *avoids* is empty, when there are demonstrably existent paths of length only 4.

This suggests to me that either my algorithm (below) is incorrect, or there are problems with my graph data structure.  It will be more difficult to check the latter, so I figured I would see if anyone spots a problem below first.

So, can you see any reason the algorithm below would find shorter paths when *avoids* is non-empty than when it's empty?

Note: "this" is the origin, and the destination ("dest") is an argument.

Thanks

```
public LinkedList<String> shortestPath(Wordnode dest, int limit, HashSet<Wordnode> avoids)
{
    HashSet<Wordnode> visited = new HashSet<>();
    HashMap<Wordnode, Wordnode> previous = new HashMap<>();
    LinkedList<Wordnode> q = new LinkedList<Wordnode>();
    previous.put(this, null);
    q.add(this);
    Wordnode curr = null;
    boolean found = false;
    while(!q.isEmpty() && !found)
    {
        curr = q.removeLast();
        visited.add(curr);
        if(curr == dest)
            found = true;
        else
        {
            for(Wordnode n: curr.neighbors)
            {
                if(!visited.contains(n) && !avoids.contains(n))
                {
                    q.addFirst(n);
                    previous.put(n, curr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(!found)
        return null;
    LinkedList<String> ret = new LinkedList<>();
    while(curr != null)
    {
        ret.addFirst(curr.word);
        curr = previous.get(curr);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The BFS is not correct: you mark your vertices at the wrong place.

You should mark them when you push them to the queue, otherwise the same vertex can be treated several time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is how you build the edge list using the `previous` map.  You store the last seen edge when queuing nodes, but this edge may not be lie on the shortest path.

You check for `dest` when you pull it from the queue, but the edge stored in `previous` for the `dest` node may no longer be the edge that was followed to get to `dest` when it was added to the queue.

When you provide `avoids` nodes you skip the process of updating the edges in `previous` so you *may* end up with a shorter path - it is not whether `avoids` is specified or not, but rather whether `avoids` contains nodes on the longer path that may 'corrupt' the edge list.

Comment: Good catch.  So there's a chance I'm overwriting initial 'previous' values.  So I need to only do previous.put(n, curr) if there isn't already an entry in previous for n.  I could do call containsKey, but that would hurt the runtime... maybe I'll have to override HashSet to only put(k, v) if there's currently no value for k and otherwise leave it alone.

Comment: Actually since it's a HashMap, containsKey should be pretty harmless.  And this solves my problem.  Only do previous.put(n, curr) if !previous.containsKey(n).

Answer (score 1):

Your BFS is correct. The problem is how you write the found path. The shortest path in BFS means "the number of **levels** away from a source to a destination". But you are counting the number of unique nodes that was looked on your way from the source to destination.

Consider the graph of 3 nodes each connected to each other:

```
    B
  /  
A   |
  \ 
    C
```

The path A-C is 1 level long. Your implementation can give the path length of 2, because nodes can visited as A-B and then C. The order will depend on your input data.
So you need to count levels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer here because none of the previous indicates the correct error.

The problem is where the nodes are marked as visited: in the original it is done when the node is popped from the queue, which means that until a given node reach the top of the queue it may be added several time and thus altering the path construction.

You must mark your node when enqueuing them so, after the line queue.addFirst(n) just add visited.add(n).